# Common Lisp Programming

Tags: lisp

I am new to lisp language. just 3 days into it.
i have an assignment and i need help in writing the codes.

Write a Lisp function that takes three arguments: a list of integers called aList, an integer called min, and an integer called max. The function returns the number of elements in aList that fall in the range min <= x <=max, where x is an element of aList. If aList is empty, the function should return 0.

Is this the right way do it.

```
(defun countem(aList min max)
  (if (> min max) 
      (cons min (aList (add1 min) max))))
```

Comment: You are referring to `x` and `y` but they don't even exist. Did you just copy-paste the body of the function from elsewhere?

Comment: What do you mean? is that not the way to do it?

Comment: @user3571154 Try `(+ 1 1)` in your REPL.

Comment: What is REPL? does that return integers between min and max???

Comment: i tried something new. I think this works. how should i test it?                                                       (defun countem(aList min max)
(if (> min max) 
      (cons min (aList (add1 min) max))))

Comment: So how you do loop over the elements of a list?

Comment: @user3571154 I bet one of the most recent things you discussed in your course were taking apart a list using `car` (or `first`) and `cdr` (or `rest`), and recursion over lists. That would be a good starting point. (Hint: You're not going to use `cons` at all.)

Comment: @user3571154 REPL = read, evaluate, print loop. It's the interactive prompt environment for LISP. To test your function, just type it in at he prompt, then run it at the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [sbcl](http://www.sbcl.org/getting.html)
2. Type in your code in REPL and have a try

reference code to find the number of elements in aList that fall in the range min <= x <=max:

```
(defun countem-1 (aList min max)
       (let ((count 0))
         (dolist (el aList)
           (if (and (>= el min) (<= el max))
               (setf count (1+ count))))
         (print count)))
```

or you means the recursive fashion:

```
(defvar count 0)
(defun countem-2 (aList min max)
       (if (<= min max)
           (progn
             (setf count (1+ count))
             (countem-2 aList (1+ min) max))
           (print count))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it.

```
(defun countem (aList min max)
  (apply #'+ (mapcar (lambda (x) (if (<= min x max) 1 0)) aList)))
```

I create a list of ones and zeros telling if the elements satisfy the constraint by mapping an anonymous function over the list.

Then I sum it up.

No looping or recursion required.